# Sparkle The update will be rejected

Tags: sparkle

I am using Xamarin to make a MAC application.
To fetch updates I am using Sparkle Framework.
I have signed old built and new build and included public in both.
But still i receive error  "The update archive isn't signed with a DSA key, and the old app hasn't been signed with app Code Signing. At least one method of signature verification must be valid. The update will be rejected"

Comment: Answered here: https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle/issues/1054

Comment: Can i ask how did you put Sparkle on Xamarin.Mac? I have tried to use the NetSparkle and NetSparkle.New packages on nuget and it doesn't work.